# Ruby on Rails model custom to_s method, exclude nill or blank values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following model defined (Using Mongoid, not active record)

```
class Address
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :extra, type: String
  field :street, type: String
  field :area, type: String
  field :city, type: String
  field :code, type: Integer

  validates :street, :city, presence: true

  def to_s
    "#{extra},#{street},#{area},#{city},#{code}"
  end
end
```

I am defining the to_s method, so i can just use:

```
<%= address %>
```

in my views, and it will print out the address correctly. However the issue with the code above, if any of the attributes are blank or nil i end up with the following:

```
1.9.3p327 :015 > a
 => #<Address _id: 50f2da2c8bffa6e877000002, _type: nil, extra: "hello", street: nil, area: nil, city: nil, code: nil> 
1.9.3p327 :016 > puts a
hello,,,,,
 => nil
```

Using a bunch of unless statements to check if the value is blank or nil seems like the wrong way to go (i can get it to work like that, but seems hackish)

What would be a better way of doing this?

Comment: Btw, you have `#{street}` twice. Is this intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
def to_s
  [extra, street, area, city, code].select{|f| !f.blank?}.join(',')
end
```

Store elements in an array, throw invalid values out, join with separator.

Comment: Just to better understand the code above better: the code is calling the select method on an array, to filter. Using a Lambda {} and then calling join on the filtered array?... is that correct?

Comment: Hey man, i made an edit to your code. It was actually giving an error on the last attribute (code), since that's an integer and does not support  the empty? method, changed it .blank? and it works, nil also evaluates to false on the .blank? method, so there is also no need for &&

Comment: my previous comment (about compact) was wrong, since compact would allow empty strings. However, a more positive version of this is `select(&:present?)` or `select{|f| f.present?}`, since .present? is defined as !blank?